# Apache Thrift Union C Glib example

Tags: java, c, serialization, thrift, unions

I am trying to serialize `Thrift` union in `C` and then deserialize in `Java`. On Java side I always get serialized only first field of union. May be someone faced similar issue?

Thrift 0.9.3

messages.thrift:

```
struct JLException {
...
}

struct JLFrame {
...
}

union JLMessage {
    1: JLException exc,
    2: JLFrame frame
}
```

**Serialization code in C** (I replaced with "..." unnecessary parts):

```
JLException* jlExeption = g_object_new(TYPE_J_L_EXCEPTION, ... , NULL);

if (jlExeption) {
    JLMessage* jlMessage = g_object_new(TYPE_J_L_MESSAGE, "exc", jlExeption, NULL);

    serialize_and_send_thrift_message((ThriftStruct*) jlMessage,
        THRIFT_STRUCT_CLASS(J_L_MESSAGE_GET_CLASS(jlMessage)));

    g_object_unref(jlExeption);
    g_object_unref(jlMessage);
}

JLFrame* jlFrame = g_object_new(TYPE_J_L_FRAME, ... , NULL);

if (jlFrame) {
    JLMessage* jlMessage = g_object_new(TYPE_J_L_MESSAGE, "frame", jlFrame,
        NULL);

    serialize_and_send_thrift_message((ThriftStruct*) jlMessage,
        THRIFT_STRUCT_CLASS(J_L_MESSAGE_GET_CLASS(jlMessage)));

    g_object_unref(jlFrame);
    g_object_unref(jlMessage);
}
```

**Deserialization code in Java**:

```
TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer();
JLMessage message = new JLMessage();

try {
    byte[] binData = tuple.getBinary(0);
    deserializer.deserialize(message, binData);
} catch (TException e) {
    _logger.error(e);
}

if (JLMessage._Fields.EXC.equals(message.getSetField())) {
    _logger.info("Received EXCEPTION message");
} else if (JLMessage._Fields.FRAME.equals(message.getSetField())) {
    _logger.info("Received FRAME message");
}
```

As a result on Java side only "Received EXCEPTION message" is logged. For `JLFrame` messages it receives empty `JLException` message.

Comment: It's possible the C library does not yet support what you're trying to do. If you believe your code is correct and you can reliably reproduce the issue, please file a bug in [Apache's bug-tracking system](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT).

Comment: Thank you for advice, I am pretty sure in my code because it works correctly with structs but not with union only

Comment: It's very possible you've found a bug then. Unfortunately I won't be able to look more closely at this today but if nobody else appears with a solution, I can help you diagnose this next week.

Comment: Opened issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3675

Comment: "*May be someone faced similar issue?*" -- yes someone did, and he was faster :-) Close as duplicate of [THRIFT-3650](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3650). I fixed that just a few days ago. For cause and workaround see there.

Comment: Ok, thank you, will try workaround on Monday

Comment: Just double checked it again with optional union fields and confirm that workaround works with C Glib as well.
Thanks again for quick response!